# I have 2 textboxes , textbox1 has a fixed time " HH:mm", Textbox2 should have textbox1 time plus 10 minutes

Tags: c#

I have a small application with 2 labels, label1.text is showing a fixed time "HH:mm" witch is assigned once a day by a timer. The second label2.text should show label1 time + 30 minutes, example if time in label1.text is 12:00 then it should be 12:30 in label2.text. I already added an other timer that should do the calculation for assigning new calculated time, but since I am new in C# I could not make it work. Any idea where to start? Thanks.

Comment: You are asking about window application or web application?

Comment: The DateTime class has methods for adding and subtracting dates and times

Answer (score 1):

As @ADyson pointed out there are methods for working with DateTime e.g. various Add methods (see [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netcore-3.1)) so if this is WinForms the following should work. In the future please use a tag to represent the type of project you are working with.

Simple example (replace labels with TextBox works too). Here the second labels adds 30 minutes to the current time, replace 30 with 10 or whatever you desire)

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm");
    label2.Text = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30).ToString("hh:mm");
    timer1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is a WinForms with a timer that assign a fixed time example : 05:00 to label1  that changes once a day in other hand label2 should show same label1 time  + 30 minutes. if Label1 time is : 05:00 then label2 should show automatically 05:30.

Comment: "did not work" tells me nothing. The code posted works in a new form with two labels and one timer.

Comment: I tried this form but no luck:             String str = Convert.ToString(this.LblTime1.Text);
            LblTime11.Text = str.AddMinutes(30).ToString;

Comment: Since you are adding 30 minutes to the second label after setting the first label there is no reason to be using Convert.ToString, use what I presented. Also note .Text property of the label is a string thus zero reasons to perform a conversion. Can you see why str.AddMinutes(30).ToString;  will not work?

Comment: Finally I came to good result and worked this way:            DateTime OldTime = Convert.ToDateTime(LblTime1.Text);
            DateTime NewTime = OldTime.AddMinutes(30);           
            LblTime2.Text = NewTime.ToString("HH:mm");
            TmrIkama.Stop(); // Thank you